# Reduction of order of 2nd order ODE (without $y_0$ or $y_1$ provided)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Please help to reduce $y''+y'=0$.
There are no initial condition nor a solution to start from.

From a similar question, I've tried a suggestion to let $W = y'$. But don't come to an agreeable results. And I'm not sure what's the cause. Here is my work so far:
$$y''+y'=0\to W'+W=0\to \frac{dW}{dx}=-W\to \int -\frac{dW}{W} = \int dx$$
and so $-\ln(W)=x+C$ which means $W=Ae^{-x}$.

But, when I plug it back into $y$ (after integrating it) it doesn't seem to work.

So two questions: How to solve this ODE, and how to approach 2nd Order ODE reduction problem without a solution and initial condition given?

Comment: Remember to integrate once more, since $W=y'$

Comment: Why is there an $A$ now in my question. I'm confused.

Comment: @JasonM, I didn't want to include that part. But may be I'm missing something there. $-ce^x = dy/dx$, then $y=-ce^x$. And this doesn't seem to help with the ODE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your almost there! 
Your answer $W=Ae^{-x} $ is spot on, except $W=\frac{dy}{dx}$, therefore $y=\int{W}dx$, so $y=C_1e^{-x}+C_2$

$C_1$ is simply a constant, and is equal to -A

$C_2$ is the constant of integration, from integrating W
Since there are two parameters for our solution to y, our solution is a 2 parameter family of solutions. 
Try testing this with the original equation, $y'' + y' = 0 $
 $y' = -C_1e^{-x},$
$ y'' = C_1e^{-x}$.
$y'' + y' = C_1e^{-x} + -C_1e^{-x} = 0  $, therefore this is indeed a solution!

The value you gave for W is just coincidentally equal to the value of -y, since $e^{-x}$ was its solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I'm just confused about this $A$. So in my case $A=e^{-c}$ ?But then where did $A$ go when I integrate $\int W dx$?

Comment: Terribly sorry about that! I forgot to clarify that, and I also forgot to add the constant of integration! When W is integrated, we are integrating $\int{Ae^{-x}}$ which is equal to $-Ae^{-x}$. I redefined -A as C because it was just a constant term. At the time I forgot about the constant of integration from integrating W, so -A should actually be equal to $C_1$, which would then be equal to $-e^{-c}$ where lowercase c is the constant your talking about in your comment. So A is still there, just labeled as $C_1$ to make seeing that it is a 2 parameter family of solutions more clear.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This helped a lot!